# Question about returning string in c language

Tags: c, string, function

```
#include<stdio.h>
char*display();

int main() {

    char*one=NULL;

    one=display();

    one[3]='9';

    printf("%s",one);//doubt(why we are not using the de reference operator)
}


char*display(){

    static char a[30]="hello";   

    return a; 

}
```

why we are not using the de reference operator(*) for displaying the value at the string ,instead we simply put the pointer variable pointing towards the string to print that string.

Comment: because thats how strings work, printf expects a pointer to the first character

Answer (score 2):

> why we are not using the de reference operator(*) for displaying the value at the string ... ?

The argument that matches the `"%s"` in `printf("%s",one);` is a *pointer*, a pointer to a *string*.  A string is more like an array of characters than a pointer. Arrays cannot be received by a function, but a pointer to an array can be received.

`printf("%s...` expects a string pointer, reads the character pointed to by that pointer, prints the character, increments its copy of the pointer and repeats until a *null character* is read.

If code use `*one`, that would pass the value of the first character of the string and `printf()` would lack information about where the next characters in the string exist.

---

Notes:
`char *display()` returns a *pointer*, not a *string*.  `one`, in `main()`, then points to a *string*.

An array is not a pointer.
A pointer is not an array.